# Hide the line "Drag a column header and drop it here to group by that column"

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a simple Kendo UI grid and I do not need Drag and Drop functionality on columns. I hence want to hide the following line:

Drag a column header and drop it here to group by that column

Can some one guide how to hide the same?

Answer (score 3):

Please set the property "groupable: false" in your kendo-Grid. For demo please check the below code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
                    },
                    pageSize: 20
                },
                height: 550,
                groupable: false, // Please set here true/false and check it
                sortable: true,
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 5
                },
                columns: [{
                    template: "<div class='customer-photo'" +
                                    "style='background-image: url(../content/web/Customers/#:data.CustomerID#.jpg);'></div>" +
                                "<div class='customer-name'>#: ContactName #</div>",
                    field: "ContactName",
                    title: "Contact Name",
                    width: 240
                }, {
                    field: "ContactTitle",
                    title: "Contact Title"
                }, {
                    field: "CompanyName",
                    title: "Company Name"
                }, {
                    field: "Country",
                    width: 150
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```